# Dataset for Bayesian Network Structure Learning

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, bayesian-networks

After tons of researches, I didn't find a repository with the necessary material to test a algorithm able to learn the structure of a Bayesian Network. What I need are only 2 things:

- the correct Bayesian Network
- a Dataset related to the BN

My algorithm should be able to learn the structure from the dataset and then I could check how far from the right BN it is. Do you have any links? I've already found some dataset without the original BN and viceversa but I need both of them for my university project.

Thanks in advance

PS: if you are interested, I use Python for my project.

Comment: perhaps you've already found what you're looking for, but if not, have you checked out the classic Grade/Recommendation Letter example from Daphne Koller's class? https://pythonhosted.org/libpgm/unittestdict.html

Comment: Also, your requirement for the 'correct' Bayesian Network seems odd. It brings to mind Box's famous quote, "All models are wrong but some are useful". A bayesian network is just a model. If you want to use an artificial example to test your structure learning algo, you can just define any model and then sample from it to generate the data from the 'correct' model.

Comment: R's `bnlearn` provides a repository of datasets of various graph formats at https://www.bnlearn.com/bnrepository/

Answer (score 1):

Try the [bnlearn library](https://erdogant.github.io/bnlearn/). It contains **structure learning**, **parameter learning**, **inference** and various example datasets such as *sprinkler, asia, alarm*, and many more.

- Various examples can be found [here](https://erdogant.github.io/bnlearn/).
- Blog about detecting causal relationships can be found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-step-by-step-guide-in-detecting-causal-relationships-using-bayesian-structure-learning-in-python-c20c6b31cee5).

Example for structure learning and making inferences:

```
# Load library
import bnlearn as bn

# Load Asia DAG
DAG = bn.import_DAG('asia')

# plot ground truth    
G = bn.plot(DAG)

# Sampling
df = bn.sampling(DAG, n=10000)

# Structure learning
model_sl = bn.structure_learning.fit(df, methodtype='hc', scoretype='bic')

# Plot based on structure learning of sampled data
bn.plot(model_sl, pos=G['pos'], interactive=True)

# Compare networks and make plot
# bn.compare_networks(model, model_sl, pos=G['pos'])
```